# find average value and above average value using def function in python

Tags: python, average

here is my code so far. I'm not sure whether I do something wrong on the code because the average seems to be wrong. please help me. Thank you

```
def enter_score ():
    results = []
    scores = int(input("How many results to enter? : "))
    for i in range(scores):
        student_name = input("enter student name: ")
        student_score = int(input("Please enter score for student " + student_name + " : " ))
        results.append(student_score)
        results.append(student_name)
        print(results)
    return results

def calc_average():
    total=0
    total=total+student_score
    average= total/scores
    print("the average is ", average)
    return
def above_average():
  above_average=0
  for i in range (scores):
    if results [i] > average:
        above_average = above_average + 1
        print(" the above average score is ", above_average)
    return above_average

enter_score()
calc_average()
above_average()
```

Comment: Why you put student names and their scores into the same list?

Comment: @Marcin i put student names and scores in the same list so that i can return the value to the empty list

Comment: Is this from a course or is it GCSE related because it seems to be repeated almost daily?

Comment: @Don Khalil you should probably create a student object that has a name and score. then append the objects to the list.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes it is from my python course at my college. really? I'd be happy to delete the post if you could point me where the similar post is.

Comment: I answered a few but they are buried somewhere in my answers. A collections.defaultdict will be useful and also statistics.mean

Answer (score 1):

You're making a list `results` that contains scores and names alternating -- very hard to use.  You return that list from `enter_score`, then completely ignore -- you throw it away!  So the other two functions are supposed to work on some magic, or thin air...?

Clearly, the overall flow at the end must instead be:

```
results = enter_score()
average = calc_average(results)
above_average(results_average)
```

and `calc_average` must end with `return average`.

`results` is better arranged by replacing the two `results.append` calls with a single one:

```
results.append((student_score, student_name))
```

i.e, make it a list of tuple, not a weird mix of numbers and names.

The other two functions clearly must loop on that list (which they now receive as an argument) to do their respective jobs.

So:

```
def calc_average(results):
    total = 0
    for student_score, student_name in results:
        total=total+student_score
    average= total/float(len(results))
    print(average)
    return average
```

and:

```
def above_average(average, results):
    above_average = 0
    for student_score, student_name in results:
        if student_score > average:
            above_average += 1
    print(" the number of above average scores is ", above_average)
    return above_average
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed/ammended your code so that it works:

```
def enter_score ():
    results = []
    scores = int(input("How many results to enter? : "))
    for i in range(scores):
        student_name = input("enter student name: ")
        student_score = int(input("Please enter score for student " + student_name + " : " ))        
        results.append((student_name, student_score))
        print(results)
    return results

def calc_average(results):
    total=0
    for student_name, student_score in results:
        total=total+student_score
    average= total/len(results)
    print("the average is ", average)
    return average

def above_average(results, average_score):
    above_average_no=0
    for student_name, student_score in results:
        if student_score > average_score:
            above_average_no = above_average_no + 1
            print(" the above average score is ", above_average_no)
    return above_average_no

results = enter_score()
average_score = calc_average(results)

above_average_no = above_average(results, average_score)
```

I wont provide detailed explanation on what and why things changes. Leave it to you to figure it out. Please note that I tried to make minimal changes to your code. Many things could be improved, such as calculating `sum`, etc. Hope this helps.